# Dynamic if statement in dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary-comprehension

I am using a dictionary comprehension to get a dictionary of key value pairs where the key is the name of an mp3 file and the value is the path to the file.

I do:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown='true'):
    source_files = {filename:root for filename in files if os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() == '.mp3'}
    # more code
    # ...
    # ...
```

I do more logic with the source files in the `more code` part.  Now, I want to repeat this logic for any pictures (i.e. .gif, .jpeg etc)

So I could do:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown='true'):
    source_files = {filename:root for filename in files if os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() == '.jpeg' or os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() == '.gif'}
```

and then wrap the `more code` part into a function and call it for the picture files.  However, I am wondering could I just make the if expression dynamic in the dictionary comprehension and then just pass in one if expression for music files and another if expression for the picture files?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) function instead, or even [`fnmatch.filter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter)

```
from fnmatch import filter

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    source_files = {filename: root for filename in filter(files, '*.jpg')}
```

But if you need to match multiple extensions, it's much easier to use [`str.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    source_files = {filename: root for filename in files if filename.endswith(('.jpg', '.png', '.gif'))}
```

Using `.endswith()` you can then use any string or tuple of extensions:

```
mp3s = '.mp3'
images = ('.jpg', '.png', '.gif')
```

then use:

```
extensions = images

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    source_files = {filename: root for filename in files if filename.endswith(extensions)}
```

I'm not sure why you are using a dict comprehension here; each iteration of the loop, `root` will be constant. You may as well do:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    source_files = dict.fromkeys(filter(files, '*.jpg'), root)
```

or use

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir):
    source_files = dict.fromkeys([f for f in files if f.endswith(extensions)], root)
```

If you wanted to create a dictionary of *all* files in a nested directory structure, you'll need to move the dict comprehension *out* and integrate the `os.walk()` call in the dict comprehension instead:

```
source_files = {filename: root 
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir)
    for filename in files if f.endswith(extensions)}
```

I removed all the `topdown='true'` lines; the default is `topdown=True` anyway (note: python booleans are `True` and `False`, not strings. It happened to work because `'true'` as a string is 'truthy', it's considered True in a boolean context because it is non-empty).

Answer (score 0):

Does this:

```
def a_func(extension):
    # some code
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootDir, topdown='true'):
        source_files = {filename:root for filename in files if os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() == extension}
        # more code
        # ...
        # ...
```

fit your needs?